# Как узнать пароль root пользователя для базы данных MySQL в Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-faq

Мне достался один VPS сервер, в наследство, так скажем. Бывший владелец не выходит на связь. Как мне узнать пароль root пользователя для базы данных MySQL? Где он храниться в файловой системе Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть замечательная статья с простыми шагами как сбросить рутовый пароль в MySQL: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password

Comment: Ответ - ссылка!

Comment: списибо, кэп :)

Comment: Очевидная проблема в ответе ссылкой - она перестанет работать. Как вышло сейчас

Answer (score 10):

узнать пароль — естественно, никак (разве что бывший владелец записал его где-нибудь «для памяти»).

но можно установить свой собственный пароль. описано это в интернетах множество раз. повторю для истории:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

цифры ("5.5") в вашей системе могут отличаться. в дефолтной установке работает `bash-completion`, поэтому, набрав всю команду вплоть до `mysql-server` и нажав два раза <kbd>tab</kbd>, вы увидите, какая именно версия пакета `mysql-server` установлена в вашей системе.

если с автодополнением не вышло, можно узнать версию, например, так:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql-server-
```

примерный вывод этой команды:

```
mysql-server-5.5                                install
mysql-server-core-5.5                           install
```

Answer (score 4):

**Остановите MySQL service**

Ubuntu and Debian:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

CentOS, Fedora, Red Hat Enterprise Linux

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

**Запустить MySQL без пароля**

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

**Подключение к MySQL**

```
mysql -uroot
```

**Установить новый пароль MySQL root**

```
use mysql;

update user set password=1234 where User='root';

flush privileges;

quit
```

**Остановка и запуск службы MySQL**

Ubuntu and Debian

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
...
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

CentOS, Fedora, and Red Hat Enterprise Linux

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
...
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

**Войдите в базу данных**

```
mysql -u root -p 1234
```