# Как настроить phpmyadmin на linux

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, phpmyadmin

при установке, используя команды `apt-get install phpmyadmin`, получил окно настройки `dbconfig-common`, ввел все данные, но в конце появилась ошибка:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using  │ │ password: YES)

как получить доступ к mysql, чтобы завершить настройку phpmyadmin?

Comment: наверно, вы ввели не тот пароль. у субд *mysql* — свой собственный набор пользователей, никак не пересекающийся с пользователями операционной системы. подключиться к субд с помощью команды `$ mysql -uroot -p` получается?

Comment: если нет — попробуйте [переустановить пароль для пользователя *mysql* с именем *root*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427773/178576).

Answer (score 1):

наверно, вы ввели не тот пароль. у субд *mysql* — свой собственный набор пользователей, никак не пересекающийся с пользователями операционной системы.

если подключиться к субд с помощью команды `$ mysql -uroot -p` и вводом того пароля, который вы использовали, не получается, значит, попробуйте [переустановить пароль для пользователя mysql с именем root](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427773/178576).

а после этого можно будет повторить послеустановочное конфигурирование пакета *phpmyadmin*:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```