# Помогите сбросить пароль mysql в ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, пароль

Не могу сбросить пароль от мускуля:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

[ok]

$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

[1] 6302 $ 150927 15:21:29 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
150927 15:21:29 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
150927 15:21:29 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать пароль root пользователя для базы данных MySQL в Ubuntu?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427757/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-root-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-mysql-%d0%b2-ubuntu)

Comment: Ну почти, дело в том что я знаю два способа как это делать, и в обоих у меня случалась ошибка. Тот вопрос решен, поэтому я подумал, что мне там никто не ответит.

Comment: @mr_blond97, правильно подумали, раз те решения не помогают, то тут вопрос не его дубликат.

Comment: вероятно, не все процессы mysqld завершились после команды `... stop`. «убейте» их: `sudo pkill -KILL mysqld`.

Comment: есть сдвиги, отписался ниже

Answer (score 2):

При установки MySQL из пакетов в ubuntu, помимо root имеется также системный пользователь debian-sys-maint, если вы не удаляли этого пользователя, то посмотреть его пароль можно в файле /etc/mysql/debian.cnf. Файл доступен для чтения только из под суперпользователя. Используя этого пользователя можно переназначить пароль MySQL-пользователю root-у при помощи команды

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('пароль');
```

Answer (score 0):

Зашел под рутом, сделал все то же самое, сработало.

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
# ps axu
# sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Выводит сообщение:

```
150927 16:24:06 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
150927 16:24:06 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
150927 16:24:06 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

Жду минут 15, ^C, смотрю процессы:

```
# ps axu
```

Внезапно в процессах не оказалось мускуля. Радуюсь, продолжаю:

```
# mysql -u root

mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> \q

# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

С одной стороны вопрос решен, с другой не понятно, почему не работало под нерутовым пользователем

Comment: с помощью `sudo` вы выполняете команды от имени другого пользователя (по умолчанию — это пользователь *root*). поэтому дело не в пользователе (в обоих случаях он один и тот же — *root*), а в том, что я вам уже написал в [этом комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453938/#comment487778_453938).

Comment: ясно, незавершенные процессы.