# Почему MySQL не дает phpMyAdmin работать?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Только начинаю работать с phpMyAdmin с помощью XAMPP (ОС - Lubuntu 14) . XAMPP установила вчера, через консоль запустились Apache, MySQL, ProFTTDP. Единственное, MySQL при перезапуске дает - not running, но потом включается.

Проблема в phpMyAdmin - при попытке туда зайти, выдает

> Welcome to phpMyAdmin Error
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> Cannot connect: invalid settings.
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Нашла, что нужно исправить тип аутентификации и пароль в config.inc.php. После этого выдает:

> Welcome to phpMyAdmin Wrong username/password. Access denied.

что можно с этим сделать, кроме переустановки? Понимаю только, что беда с MySQL.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать пароль root пользователя для базы данных MySQL в Ubuntu?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427757/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-root-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-mysql-%d0%b2-ubuntu)

Comment: Какой логин и пароль вы вводите? Успешно ли входите в консоль mysql с использованием этого аккаунта?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что phpMyAdmin может устанавливаться со своей собственной базой данных, в которой он хранит предпочтения пользователей, настройки, историю и т.п. Для обслуживания этой базы данных может быть заведен отдельный пользователь, который в терминологии phpMyAdmin называется controluser. Если вы используете базу данных phpMyAdmin (а он может работать без нее), если вы используете выделенного пользователя controluser (а phpMyAdmin может обслуживать собственную базу данных и без него), следует убедиться, что такой пользователь создан, его логин и пароль прописаны в конфигурационном файле phpMyAdmin - config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
```

Если вы не планируете использовать базу данных phpMyAdmin закомментируйте эти строки, а также

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
```

Если вы используете тип аутентификации config, т.е. прописываете в config.inc.php имя пользователя и его пароль, чтобы входить в phpMyAdmin не задавая их каждый раз, то в выделенном пользователе для обслуживания данных phpMyAdmin нет надобности, можно использовать аккаунт для входа:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```