# Не может подключиться к сокету

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, настройка

Установил `mysql-server через apt-get install` на ubuntu 16.04.
Пароль для root почему-то не спросил при установке.

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=root
mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through
socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Пытаюсь сбросить пароль, но что-то ничего не работает.
Что делать?

Comment: Ошибка говорит скорее о том, что mysql вообще не запущен. Посмотрите логи mysql и остается ли он запущен

Comment: При перезапуске, конец error-лога
2016-04-26T09:04:43.020707Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2016-04-26T09:04:43.027673Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-04-26T09:04:43.027904Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.12-0ubuntu1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2016-04-26T09:04:43.599324Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427773/178576

Answer (score 2):

Данная ошибка сообщает о том, что у вас не запущен MySQL-сервер. Смотрите, вы останавливаете MySQL-сервер штатными средствами Ubuntu

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Вслед за этим пытаетесь запустить сервер в обход команды `service`, не указывая ни пути к сокету, ни пути к каталогу данных

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=root
```

Это не очень хорошая идея, вы наверняка что-то забудете или не учтете. Если вам необходимо запустить сервер MySQL без таблицы привилегий, лучше временно отредактировать конфигурационной файл my.cnf (в ubuntu он расположен по пути /etc/mysql/my.cnf) и добавить в секцию [mysqld] директиву `skip-grant-tables`

```
[mysqld]
...
skip-grant-tables
```

После этого запустите сервер штатными средствами Ubuntu

```
sudo service mysql start
```

PS Кроме того, в папке /etc/mysql/ вы обнаружите файл debian.cnf, в котором имеется пароль системного пользователя debian-sys-maint - у него тоже права суперпользователя, в случае чего можно зайти из под него и настроить пароль и права других пользователей, включая root.