# Не пускает в mysql из под обычного пользователя

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Только что установил свежую ubuntu 16.04, на неё поставил mysql, но при попытки зайти в неё

```
$ mysql -uroot
```

выдается ошибка

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

хотя, я всё-таки могу туда зайти через

```
$ sudo mysql -uroot
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы из под обычного пользователя туда заходить?

---

добавлено из комментария:

Поставил через

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

предлагалось установить пароль для пользователя mysql root, я оставил пустым, и если пытаюсь зайти с флагом -p система запрашивает пароль, я нажимаю enter, и выдается та же ошибка.

Comment: 1. каким именно образом вы «поставили» сервер mysql и клиент mysql? 2. при этой «постановке» вам предлагалось создать пароль для пользователя root в сервере mysql? 3. если да, то этот пароль подходит в ответ на запрос пароля при выполнении `mysql -u root -p`? 4. в домашнем каталоге пользователя, под именем которого вы работаете, имеется файл `.my.cnf`? 5. в домашнем каталоге пользователя root имеется файл `.my.cnf`?

Comment: Поставил через `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` и `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`, да предлагалось, я оставил пустым, если пытаюсь зайти с флагом -p система запрашивает пароль, я нажимаю enter, и выдается та же ошибка. Файла *.my.cnf* нет не в `~`, ни в `/root`

Comment: значит, вам сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427773/178576

Comment: то-есть получается что нельзя разрешить руту без пароля в базу входить?

Comment: увы, не уловил смысла последнего вопроса. если вам не хочется вводить пароль, создайте файл `~/.my.cnf` с [соответствующим содержимым](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521112/178576).

Answer (score 4):

как в *debian*-основном дистрибутиве переустановить пароль для пользователя root mysql, описано, например, в этом ответе: [Как узнать пароль root пользователя для базы данных MySQL в Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427773/178576)

чтобы не вводить пароль каждый раз при вызове клиента mysql, можно использовать пользовательский конфигурационный файл: [Как указать значения по умолчанию при запуске клиента mysql?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521113/178576)

Comment: переустановил пароль
`mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("123") where User='root';` (серевер презагрузили через `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`)
все равно таже ошибка
`mysql -uroot -p123`

> mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: @Ghost16, я же указал ссылку на *правильный дистрибутивный* метод изменения пароля пользователя root в mysql.

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать нового пользователя с полными правами.

```
$ sudo mysql -uroot

CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;

$ mysql -unewuser -ppassword
```

Для работы с базой использовать нового пользоваателя newuser вместо root.

Answer (score 0):

В MariaDB Debian 9.5:

```sql
sudo mysql -u root 
use mysql; 
update user set plugin='' where User='root';-- Want be the Empty string!!!
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста [поправте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/877463/edit) ваше сообщение. Поясните, что делает этот фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 0):

Использую такой запрос от root в Bash скриптах:

```
mysql --user=root <<_EOF_
  UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('${MYSQL_PASS}') WHERE User='root';
  DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
  DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1');
  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
  DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\\_%';
  UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
_EOF_
```

И потом делаю:

```
service mysql restart
```