# Как указать значения по умолчанию при запуске клиента mysql?

Tags: mysql, unix

как в *unix*-подобной операционной системе задать значения по умолчанию для имени хоста, базы данных, пользователя, пароля и тому полобного?

чтобы каждый раз не указывать одно и то же типа:

```
$ mysql -h хост -u пользователь -pпароль база-данных
```

а просто запускать:

```
$ mysql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) указано местоположение файла, который прочитывается клиентом *mysql* при запуске:

```
~/.my.cnf
```

в нём можно указать [все необходимые](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html) значения по умолчанию (конечно, их можно при необходимости переопределить из командной строки) в секции `[client]`:

```
[client]
host=хост
database=база-данных
user=пользователь
password=пароль
# и другие параметры для клиента mysql
```

---

для пущей безопасности имеет смысл сделать файл доступным только самому пользователю:

```
$ chmod go= ~/.my.cnf
```

---

кстати, этой файл учитывается и при запуске всех остальных программ из пакета *mysql-client*: `mysqldump`, `mysqladmin`, `mysqlcheck` и т.д. и т.п.