# Передаю в SSH-консоли Ubuntu root-пароль для mysqldump

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, безопасность, ssh, резервное-копирование

Ubuntu 16.04, mySQL 5.7

На сервере пару десятков крупных баз данных.
Для каждой БД создаю бэкап командой

```
mysqldump -uroot -p user1_db1 --opt --routines --lock-all-tables | gzip > /backup/user1_db1.sql.gz
```

При этом каждый раз запрашивается пароль root.

Ежели я вставляю этот пароль с саму команду

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword user1_db1 --opt --routines --lock-all-tables | gzip > /backup/user1_db1.sql.gz
```

то Ubuntu предупреждаем меня, что это небезопасно.

В чем заключается опасность такого метода? В том, что пароль можно будет найти в списке последних введенных команд? Этот список в последствии можно очистить?

Вообще планирую написать sh-скрипт с перечислением данной команды (с указанием пароля) для всех баз данных на сервере. Так как продолжительность создания одного бэкапа - не быстрое дело и ждать очень утомительно. Запустить этот шел и пойти пить чай, пока создаются резервные копии.

Comment: Создайте файл .my.cnf в папке /root, в нем пароль (формат файла легко найти в Сети). Это избавит от необходимости вводить пароль в mysqldump, mysql и т.д.

Comment: он уже там записан

Comment: Тогда mysqldump не должен у вас спрашивать пароль. У меня не спрашивает, и пользователя ему я не указываю. В .my.cnf у меня `[client]` `user=root` `password=пароль`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как указать значения по умолчанию при запуске клиента mysql?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521112/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-mysql)

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил в .my.cnf:  user=root . Из команды убрал -uroot -p. Пароль сейчас не спрашивает. Теперь остается гадать создается бэкап от пользователя root или от пользователя user1_db1.

Comment: Но мой вопрос также: в чем заключается опасность передачи пароля в строке команды?

Comment: список выполняющихся процессов (включая команды, которыми эти процессы были запущены) доступны любому процессу.