# Как восстановить пароль к MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользуюсь [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) и не могу подключиться к базе данных.
Где можно посмотреть или где я задавал, или как можно поменять пароль, чтобы войти?

Comment: Пароль к базе данных или к Adminer? И о чем речь? Об этом: https://www.adminer.org/en/extension/ ?

Comment: пароль который вводиться в adminer при входе

Comment: сделайте скриншот инструмента, с которым вы работаете и формы его входа без введенных данных

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать пароль root пользователя для базы данных MySQL в Ubuntu?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427757/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-root-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-mysql-%d0%b2-ubuntu)

Comment: я вообще не знаю что делать с этим админером...зашло, я пользовался, потом выкинуло и не заходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно вместо localhost набрать 127.0.0.1

Comment: И это решило проблему с забытым паролем без его восстановления?

Comment: если ты внимательно прочитаешь вопрос то я указал где я его указывал, потому что не знал почему не заходит...Но как вышло нужно было в написать именно это...я сам удевлен...просто я не мог понять как зайти потом сидел всю нось искал решение, просто писал на php и все такое и в 5 утра как-то зашел после сотни второй попыток, а потом забыл как я именно вошел, но теперь буду знать

Answer (score 2):

### Пояснение

Вам нужно не изменить (или ввести) пароль для Adminer, а изменить (или ввести) пароль пользователя MySQL.

### Как сменить пароль

В терминале выполняем команду

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.0
```

(Где mysql-server-5.0 - это ваша версия MySQL сервера)

Жмем «Enter» и вводим новый пароль.

(Работает только в Ubuntu)

---

### Как узнать версию MySQL

В терминале выполняем команду

```
mysql --version
```

Будет примерно такой вывод:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for pc-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline
```

---

#### Откуда информация

[Как восстановить пароль Mysql (Ubuntu)?](http://world-blog.ru/kak-vosstanovit-parol-mysql-ubuntu) (в статье есть иной способ восстановления пароля)
[Как узнать версию MySQL сервера](https://vps.ua/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E_MySQL_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5)

Comment: пишет вот что когда пытаюсь узнать версию ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Comment: @darkwoolf, посмотрите вот эту статью http://softodom.com/516/mysql-cant-connect-through-socket-reshenie-problemy.html и попробуйте решить эту проблему описанным в ней способом. Потом вернитесь к моему ответу.

Comment: крч, решил...вместо localhost набрал IP 127.0.0.1