# Ubuntu mysql сломался root (ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

Я недавно установил ubuntu.
Настроил Lamp для разработки на php. Протестил, вроде всё работает. Но по одному уроку я поменял auth_sock пароль для root на sha..что-то там. Теперь, когда я ввожу в терминал `sudo mysql -u root -p`. У меня как обычно запрашивается пароль. Я ввожу root (такой у меня пароль был и работал). И мне выдается такая ошибка:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Если ввести `sudo mysql -u root`, то  та же ошибка, только (using password: NO).

Пробовал `sudo mysql_secure_installation` - не помогло
Пробовал `mysqladmin -u root password [newpassword]` - не помогло

Погуглив, я нашел вариант, что нужно изменить пароль таки образом: https://qna.habr.com/q/439469
Но, когда я останавливаю сервер mysql и ввожу `mysql -u root` - выдает такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот файл есть только, когда сервер запущен

Как мне восстановить доступ для root? У меня есть пользователь admin, но я не добавил ему никаких привелегий(( И сделать он ничего не может

Comment: Точно, забыл, спасибо. Чуть позже допишу

Comment: Если есть ценные базы, то сохрани базы, находятся в директории /var/lib/mysql/. Удали MySQL и заново установи, затем замени директорию с базами на ту которую сохранил. По умолчанию это /var/lib/mysql/ директория. Если ценного там ничего нет, то смело сдувай MySQL и заново ставь без всяких сохранений.

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427773/178576)

Comment: Я пробовал `sudo apt remove mysql-server` - потом заново установил. Не помогло, всё та же ошибка. Хотя там вроде нужно ввести ещё что-то связанное с autoremove. Это я не знаю. Попробую сегодня ещё раз переустановить

Comment: при удалении пакета командой remove программы apt-get конфигурация пакета **не удаляется**. надо именно переконфигурировать. я же ссылку привёл с инструкцией. отчего бы не попробовать действовать по инструкции. раз уж другие способы не приводят к успеху?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я переустановил mysql по этой статье, а потом заново его установил
https://losst.ru/kak-udalit-mysql-v-ubuntu

`sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client`
Затем `sudo mysql_secure_installation` - проходим обычную установку.